# VS Code Intellisense can't recognize buildType or buildKit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, intellisense

I have a VS Code CMake project configured with buildTypes (debug,release) and kits (arm,...) where i have defined my CMake cross-compiled builds with:

```
{
...
"cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/../build_${buildType}_${buildKit}",
...
}
```

I've had no problems compiling my code with different kits, but i've had problems when i try to find  the correct file path that i am trying to see.
My main goal is to be able to find the correct file scrolling through the headers. For example, if a have a header:

```
#include <string>
```

I know that this file is here "../armv7at2hf-neon-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/9.2.1/string" but vscode suggest me "/usr/include/c++/10/string", which is a wrong path and a wrong file.
After trying to fix this problem. I have configured in settings.json file:

```
"C_Cpp.default.compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/../build_${buildType}_${buildKit}/compile_commands.json",
"C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
```

Finaly, I have been able to verify that intellisense doesn't recognize ${buildType} and ${buildKit}. So i manually change that with:

```
"C_Cpp.default.compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/../build_debug_arm/compile_commands.json",
"C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools`"
```

And it works. But, i have to change it whenever every time i change type or kit.

Is there any alternative or solution to configure cmake-tool or intellisense to be able to find the file correctly?

Comment: is there a reason you aren't just letting the cmake plugin configure intellisense for you?

Comment: Sorry, I edit wronly my post. My configurationProvider is "ms-vscode.cmake-tools".  I could add that i am using extension 1.12.4. And vscode version 1.72.0

Comment: you need to use `${command:cmake.buildKit}` based on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/f23388d191d376c2b062768778edee097c176aeb/docs/cmake-settings.md)

Comment: I have tried before, as well, but when i change the kit or type i get this message: Cannot find"${workspaceFolder}/../build_debug_${command:cmake.buildKit/compile_commands.json". Instead, the "includePath" value from the c_cpp_properties.json file in the "src" folder will be used.

Comment: As a workaround, you copy add a copy target in cmake to copy compile_command.json to your work space root.